# Profile unit test in Visual Studio 2017 + NUnit + Resharper

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, resharper, profile

I have a C# project in Visual Studio 2017 Professional.  It has some unit tests: methods declared with `[Test]` which display a little green tick icon in the editor, where I can right-click and 'Run' or 'Debug' the test.  When I do so, a window opens with all tests in the solution and I can click a green 'play' triangle to run them all.

I can also run my program under the profiler starting from Debug -> Performance Profiler.

So far so good.  Now, how do I run a unit test under the profiler?

When I first asked this question I looked for profiling unit tests and saw it was a feature in Visual Studio Professional.  But in fact, I'm not using VS's own unit testing support, but rather NUnit, driven by Resharper.  Sorry to throw everyone off the scent.

Comment: Did you come up with anything?

Comment: No, I never did find the answer.

Comment: which test runner do you use? default mstest?

Comment: Thanks, that was it!  Like an idiot I didn't realize that the unit tests I was running weren't normal Visual Studio ones, but NUnit, and the GUI showing them is provided by Resharper.

Comment: ...though I am no nearer knowing how to profile the tests.  At least I have better terms to Google on now.

Answer (score 4):

Using VS2017 Professional and the Diagnostic Tools you can profile code between two break points!

Thus, you can debug your unit test (xunit, nunit, mstest, whatever!) with any tool (VS Test Explorer, ReSharper, etc) like this:

1. [enable diagnostic tools while debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/general-debugging-options-dialog-box?view=vs-2017) (see [answer from tm1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56889195/3311611))
2. Set a break point at the start of your unit test, another one at the end (or wherever you like)
3. Debug the unit test with your favorite tool, you hit the first break point.
4. Open the Diagnostic Tools window (Debug > Windows > Show Diagnostic Tools)
5. Start Recording a CPU profile (small record button below all those graphs)
6. Continue (F5) to the next break point
7. VS will now create a snapshot for this period and you can dig into the relevant methods. Voila!

Just for completeness, an alternative, commercial solution is Jetbrain's DotTrace, which is part of ReSharper Ultimate at the point of writing. Here you could directly profile your unit test without manual break points.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

According to @patrick-stalph the 3-step proposed solution does not work in Visual Studio 2017 Professional.

---

## Disclaimer

I'm using *Visual Studio Enterprise 2017*, so I cannot check, whether this works in *Professional*, or not.

---

1. Open *Test Explorer* e.g. `Ctrl + Q`, then type `Test Explorer` and hit `Enter`
2. You should see your tests in *Test Explorer*. If you cannot, *Build*.
3. Choose a test, right click it, and choose *Profile Test*

## Workaround

I must note, that I'm using [xunit](/questions/tagged/xunit) and [autofixture](/questions/tagged/autofixture), and I haven't seen this feature working. See [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/353789/profiling-unit-test-fails-visual-studio-2017-xunit.html#), why I haven't.
Hence, based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210908/497026) of [Jeremy Liberman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923846/jeremy-liberman), I was able to work around using the steps below:

1. Install `xunit.runner.console` NuGet package to the test project
2. Click *Analyze* > *Performance Profiler...* from the *Toolbar*.
3. Change *Target* to *Executable*
4. Click *Start*
5. Follow the Wizard, till you reach *Choose the application that you want to profile (.EXE, .DLL, Website)*
6. Choose *An executable (.EXE file)*
7. Based on [Run tests with the xUnit.net console runner](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop#run-tests), I've specified the following values:

   - *Full path*: `c:\<...>\src\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.4.0\tools\net472\xunit.console.exe` (fit this to your environment)
   - *Command-line arguments*: `<Product>.Tests\bin\Debug\<Product>.Tests.dll`
   - *Working directory*: `c:\<...>\src\` (the root of the *Solution*)
8. *Next*, *Finish*

Note, that this profiles all of the tests in the test assembly. You can choose, which tests you want to run by providing more *Command-line arguments* to `xunit.runner.console`. To learn more about the console runner options, run the console runner with no command line options.

Comment: Using VS2017 Professional, nunit3, and the nunit test adapter my Test Explorer shows and runs my unit tests. However, There is no "profile test" button as you described.

Answer (score 1):

If you can debug and stop at a break-point, you should also be able to get CPU and memory usage according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2017), given you [enable diagnostics tools while debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/general-debugging-options-dialog-box?view=vs-2017).