# Visual studio 2015 how to profile a single unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I want to profile a single unit test , in visual studio 2015 enterprise edition

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855085/how-to-profile-performance-for-a-single-unit-test-using-visual-studio-2013-profe)  and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034375/profiling-tests-in-visual-studio-community-2015) but it is for 2013 version

was there any update on this in the 2015 edition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now a temporary solution I found , is using a 3rd party [tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html) it has a trial period of 10 days .